# Define Shadow for SeriesCollection in Chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts, shadow

I have an issue with setting the shadow to series collections in a `xlXYScatter` chart. The shadow is drawn but with ignoring all the parameters (color, transparency etc.). I think I do not call the shadow property correctly for the series collection. But I don't know how to do it right. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

```
...
With .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Shadow
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .OffsetX = 3
    .OffsetY = 3
    .Transparency = 0.4
    .Visible = True
End With
```

Comment: Have you tried creating it from the dialog boxes with the macro recorder running to see what Excel actually sets?

Comment: Hello FreeMan, I tried to use the macro recorder but without any success. What do you mean with the dialog box?

Comment: The series formatting dialog box. i.e. 1) start the macro recorder. 2) do all your formatting. 3) stop the macro recorder. Excel should spit out all the parameters necessary - If you're using 2010 or newer (perhaps 2007?), there are a lot of color palette setting that the macro recorder will give you, and these may help you.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2007 and the macro recorder doesn't work for setting shadows to the graph series collections, humph...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a solution by myself. Just for someone having the same issue. With using:

```
...
.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Shadow.Type = msoShadow21
...
```

the shadow is drawn to the series collection. The different types of shadow can be set by changing the number e.g. `msoShadow34` or `msoShadow25` etc.